# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$, satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers, open-problem

In what follows, we will denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.  A positive integer $y$ is said to be *perfect* when $\sigma(y)=2y$.  (Equivalently, $y$ is perfect when $I(y)=2$.)

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $p$, satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  It is fairly obvious that $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

By [MSE user FredH](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82711)'s proof in this [paper](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/), we know that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**.  Hence, we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
for some integer $r \geq 2$ and where $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

Here is my question:

> **Can we write $r = q - 1$ and $t = 2^q - 1$, where $2^q - 1$ is prime?**

That is, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number, can $m^2 - p^k$ be an **even perfect number**?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Assume to the contrary that we can write $m^2 - p^k$ as an even perfect number.

It follows from the considerations above that $m^2 - p^k \neq 6$, since the LHS is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$.

Thus, $r = q - 1$ is even.  I also know that $$2^{q-1} = 2^r < t = 2^q - 1.$$

I also know that it would follow from (the assumption)
$$I(2^r t) = I(m^2 - p^k) = I(p^k m^2) = 2$$
that $m^2 - p^k$ is a [*friend*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number) of the odd perfect number $p^k m^2$.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

Comment: I have skimmed through my copy of the **Handbook of Number Theory II**, Chapter 1 (PERFECT NUMBERS: OLD AND NEW ISSUES; PERSPECTIVES), Sections 1.3 (Even perfect numbers), 1.4 (Odd perfect numbers), and 1.5 (Perfect, multiperfect and multiply perfect numbers), in the hopes of finding some useful information, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: If $M_q$ is the *Mersenne prime* of an even perfect number (EPN), then the EPN takes the form $$\frac{M_q (M_q + 1)}{2}.$$

Hence, we have the (quadratic) equation
$$\frac{t(t + 1)}{2} = m^2 - p^k,$$
which gives
$$t = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{D}}{2},$$
where the discriminant
$$D = 1 + 8(m^2 - p^k)$$
needs to be a **square**.

Comment: I also know that $m^2 - p^k > 2m > 2\cdot{10}^{375}$, so not all Mersenne primes $t$ satisfy
$$\frac{t(t+1)}{2}=m^2 - p^k,$$
under the assumption that $m^2 - p^k$ is an *even perfect number* if $p^k m^2$ is an *odd perfect number*.

Comment: Okay sorry OP I always have made one of my job to prove OP with material that is related to the question title. It sometimes failed so did it now. Sorry

Comment: @JitendraSingh:  That is fine.  I have deleted my comment accordingly.

Comment: "$D=1+8(m^2-p^k)$ needs to be a square" If $m^2-p^k=2^{q-1}(2^q-1)$, then $D$ is a square since we can write $D=1+8\cdot 2^{q-1}(2^q-1)=(2^{q+1}-1)^2$.

Comment: Yes, @mathlove, that follows from basic considerations from an even perfect number being also a *triangular number*.

Comment: Further to [this comment I made last June 7, 2021 at 07:12 AM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157573/on-odd-perfect-numbers-pk-m2-with-special-prime-p-satisfying-m2-pk#comment8626456_4157573), I now know that
$$m^2 - p^k > \dfrac{m^2}{3} > \dfrac{{10}^{750}}{3}.$$